# Could I use Present continuous

Tags: present-continuous

I arrived in a hotel and the receptionist asked me if I would take the breakfast tomorrow in this hotel. He said "Will you take the breakfast" and told me that I could give my answer once  I had  made myself comfortable in my room.
I answered "ok"  and ten minutes later after making my self  comfortable  I  answered "I will take it "
Could I have answered "I'm taking the breakfast tomorrow at the hotel".

Answer (score -1):

The present continuous tense can absolutely be used to talk about an action to be completed in the future! One of the applications of the present continuous tense is precisely this. Remember the other three tenses? (will + verb infinitive without "to"), (be + going to + verb infinitive without "to"), and the present simple tense. The present continuous tense can be used in cases where you have no doubt in your mind that you are going to do something. You have thought it out well and made plans for it. Unless there is an earthquake to reduce the hotel to rubbles, by golly, you will have breakfast tomorrow morning at the hotel! So, you could've said, "I just wanted to let you know that I am having breakfast here tomorrow morning!"

Comment: If someone is downvoting my post, please provide a reason.

Comment: -1 This is a great exploration of your thoughts on the question, Bahram. However, I think there are better answers: First, *to take* (a meal) is common in some varieties of English. Though not common, I agree. But the OP didn't ask if it was common.

Comment: Second, in Standard English, we won't use the present continuous to respond to an offer in this situation. Examples of natural dialogue (when the answer is given after a delay): Q: Will you take breakfast here? A: I will take breakfast here. Q: Will you eat/have breakfast here at the hotel? A: I will eat/have breakfast here. It would be odd to include "at the hotel" in the answer.

Comment: Where in the answer did I include "at the hotel?"

Comment: "The present continuous tense is used when you have no doubt in your mind that you are going to do something." 1. *I'm thinking I won't defend my downvote further, just at the moment.* (Example of present continuous when I have a doubt in my mind.) 2. *I'll (I + will) answer the door. (When the speaker is certain, an example of certainty that does not use the present continuous.*

Comment: My statement about "at the hotel" was intended for the OP. I'll try to provide a more complete answer, supported by evidence, later.

Comment: While I understand what you are saying about "offers", Jim Reynolds, and that there are more appropriate answers, I am not so sure if we absolutely never use present continuously in this situation.

Comment: It's possible to use it. Just not the most natural choice in the situation as it's given. Let's discuss together in the chat, if you'd like. Maybe you'll end up revising this answer instead of me answering, if our explorations together lead to shared agreement! At the moment, I'm afraid I'm too busy to compose an answer.

Comment: I left out "can be used" above by mistake. Please look at the statements at the beginning. There is a reference to "one of the applications of the tense." But I will make that correction.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74096/discussion-between-bahram-and-jim-reynolds).

Comment: I thought present continuous was ok becausbefore taking my decision I had thought about it

Comment: A problem is that *I'm taking the breakfast tomorrow . . ..* sounds strange when it is a reply to the question, *Will you take breakfast tomorrow . . ..* You may now wish to think about whether your purpose is to memorize a lot of facts and rules of thumb about how to use verb tenses, or how to use them well to communicate. They are very different goals in my opinion.

Comment: I've worked in the food industry business here in the US where I heard many times customers answering with, _(I think) I'm getting a sandwitch_, for instance, to the question, _Will you order a pizza or a sandwich?_  or _I'm picking it up here_ to the question, _Will you pick up your order here or want it delivered?_ I just can't see how this type of scenario could not have played out in the OP's case.